# SQL join generates duplicate data

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

having the following case where we have 3 tables a,b,c

```
a column(phone_num)
b column(phone_num,listing_id) ----> phone number repeated for each listing
c column(listing_id)
```

I want to perform a join on the above 3 tables, but for the join between table A and B it causes data duplication. is there anyway to join the 3 tables and avoid duplicated data?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Also show the query as you have it so far. That would also help as a starting point

Comment: Add DBMS you are using

Comment: Of course it duplicates. You said yourself that there is one row per listing_id in table b.

Comment: @JohnHC yea that's why it's a problem, table B is the only way to join table A to table C

Comment: Well unless you provide some actual details the best we can do is guess as to what you want.

Comment: @MohamedAbdelHakim No, the problem is that you are expecting a single result from a table with multiple entries without explaining what you actually want to see so that we can help